# Incrementing array indices

Tags: c

I always assumed that the increment operator ++ is the same as +=1, but this does not always appear to be the case. Consider the short program:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  int b[] = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };

  // Insert a line of code here 

  printf("%d\n", i);
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    printf("%d %2d %2d\n", j, a[j], b[j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

If you insert the line:

```
a[i++] = b[i++];
```

You get the following output:

```
2
0 10 10
1  1 11
2  2 12
3  3 13
4  4 14
```

It appears that after incrementing i on the RHS, the new value is not passed to the LHS, although after that statement the value of i is 2.  However, if you replace this line with:

```
a[i+=1] = b[i+=1];
```

you get the following output:

```
2
0  0 10
1  1 11
2 12 12
3  3 13
4  4 14
```

which is most obviously different. You can play around with other combinations of ++ and +=1, as well as trying ++i, and see what happens.

As far as I know, there is no documentation on the differences between ++ and +=1. Is this dependent on the compiler or the OS? I'm using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2022. I haven't checked this with other languages such as C++, Java and JavaScript. Does anybody have any ideas or comments?